# Python code gibberish

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello and thank you for your time.
I have of late been attempting to learn Python 2.7 via 
"The hard way to learn python" by Zed A. Shaw

In one of the exercises I have encountered a minor issue but a bothersome one at that.

**The code goes as follows:**

```
from sys import argv
script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)
print "First let's print the whole file:\n"
print_all(current_file)
print "now let's rewind it kind off like a tape."
rewind(current_file)
print "let's print three lines."
current_line = 1 
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
current_line += 1
print_a_line(current_file, current_file)
current_line += 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

**And the result is:**

```
First let's print the whole file:

To all the people out there.
I say I don't like my hair.
I need to shave it off.

Now let's rewind it kind off like a tape.
let's print three lines.
1 To all the people out there.

<open file 'test.txt', mode 'r' at 0x01D16230> I say I don't like my hair.

3 I need to shave it off.
```

Everything is working just fine except the `<open file 'test.txt', mode 'r' at 0x01D16230>` which to my simplistic mind seems random.

**Why does this appear?**

NOTE: I am using notepad++ on windows 8.1

Comment: You got `current_file` instead of `current_line`

Comment: Wow.. Thank you, I swear I looked over the code several times I have no idea how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

```
print_a_line(current_file, current_file)
```

This should be

```
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

the output you see is because of

```
print line_count
```

where line_count actually refers to a file stream that was opened earlier for reading.